# Couldn't find Chessboard corners

Tags: python, opencv, calibration

My aim is to obtain the recognition of colour and position of pawns in Chessgame. The recognition was pretty easy because of many tutorials on github. With opencv functions **cv2.findChessboardCorners** and **cv2.drawChessboardCorners** (clear Chessboard) I obtained satisfied result as in the picture below:

[image: Found Chessboard Corners]

But when I try to get the corners of image with recognized pawns or of image of pawns on Chessboard (not empty Chessboard) it fail and I don't get any result.

[image: Recognized pawns]

I don't attach any code because I use only this two functions.

How could i fix that? Do i have to do any manual calibration?

I hope that someone has done something similiar and could solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is in C++ but is easily transferable to Python.

You are using the function `findChessboardCorners` of OpenCV which is actually not a function for finding corners on any possible chessboard. The function is usually used for camera calibration (determination of camera paramters) and requires e.g. a self-printed black and white chessboard. An older example can be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html). Interesting that it works also for your brown chessboard.

For finding chessboard corners I would recommend a different OpenCV workflow.
I am reading the image, applying a bilateral filter on the image to smooth the image but preserve edges and then I use the function `goodFeaturesToTrack` to find the strongest corners in the image. Since you did not provide an image with no additional lines I used a random internet image of a brown chessboard: [image: brown chessboard]The C++ code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Reading the images 
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("chessboard_2.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::Mat img_rgb = cv::imread("chessboard_2.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    cv::Mat bilateral_filtered_image;

    // Applying a bilateral filter to smooth the image
    cv::bilateralFilter(img, bilateral_filtered_image, 5, 75, 75);
    cv::namedWindow("Bilateral Filter", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::imshow("Bilateral Filter", bilateral_filtered_image);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    // Find corner points using goodFeaturestoTrack with appropriate parameters
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
    cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(bilateral_filtered_image, corners, 200, 0.01, 120);
    std::cout << corners.size() << std::endl;

    // Draw all corners on the original image and show the image
    for (size_t i = 0; i < corners.size(); ++i) {
        cv::circle(img_rgb, cv::Point2f(corners[i].x, corners[i].y), 7, (0,0,255), 3);
    }
    cv::namedWindow("Corners", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::imshow("Corners", img_rgb);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Result:
[image: Corners]